# jOOQ open source version - can no longer generate source from a schema?

Tags: jooq

Am I reading the [pricing page](https://www.jooq.org/download/) correctly?

I thought when I looked at that "footnote 8", it was telling me that the open source version no longer will generate code from a DB schema.

But the doco [code generation](https://www.jooq.org/download/) section says the open source version supports it.

If I did read the pricing page wrong, what is "Java (to generate jOOQ code) [8]" trying to communicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That page lists the supported `SQLDialect` values. The thing you're referring to specifically is [`SQLDialect.JAVA`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/SQLDialect.html#JAVA), which can be used to translate SQL to "Java code" (i.e. jOOQ code). You can try it for free here: https://www.jooq.org/translate

E.g. with this input:

```sql
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM actor
ORDER BY id DESC
```

And this meta data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE actor (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name TEXT,
  last_name TEXT
)
```

You get this output:

```java
select(
  ACTOR.FIRST_NAME,
  ACTOR.LAST_NAME
)
.from(ACTOR)
.orderBy(ACTOR.ID.desc())
```

Nothing was removed from the jOOQ Open Source Edition. Something was added to the other editions.

See the original jOOQ 3.15 feature request here:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6277

And known issues here:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11911